I'm trying to use expect to login to a remote server automatically
#!/user/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh user@xx.xx.xxx.x
expect 
  "Welcome to Interface Concept User SSH service user@xx.xx.xxx.x's password:" send "myPassword\r"

I expect eof.
This is what I have so far, however, when I run it, it doesn't log in automatically it still asks me to put in the password myself and when i do it doesn't even login.
Any help would be great, thank you!
I tried running the above script that I have to login automatically but it still asked me to type the password myself and when I did it didn't even log me in.
And I know I'm missing brackets.... I know it's poorly written but it didn't like the brackets

while developing an expect script, run it with expect -d script.exp to see the verbose output. That will let you see why your patterns don't match.

Expect is built on Tcl, which is a very whitespace-sensitive language. Without brackets, the patten must be on the same line as the expect command. And the send command must be on a new line.
